# Shorten a long Replace function within an SQL Data String

Tags: string, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures, replace

I've been tasked with fixing some issues on an existing Stored Procedure which funnels the SELECT and JOIN statements into a string for insertion into a table with a single 'Data' column.

I am working in SQL Server Manager 2008 R2.

I am pulling data from a table(SourceTable) in another database, and one of the columns (SourceDataColumn) from the SourceTable may contain any one of the following codes: A, B, C, D, or E.  I have added several REPLACE statements so that A=01, B=02, and C, D, or E = 03.  As you can see from the code (Stored Proc greatly shortened for clarity), I have to use the REPLACE keyword several times in the same line. There is a separate REPLACE for C, D, and E, but there must be some way to combine the C, D, and E replacements in a more concise way?

Is there a way to shorten this code, or make it less redundant?  Keep in mind that I'm having to write this script within a string variable so the syntax, at least to me, seems more tricky than writing a regular query sans INSERT.

```
    SET @SQLScript=  
   'INSERT INTO FOO_BAR_Data  
    (  
     PrimaryId  
    ,Data  
    )  
    SELECT DISTINCT  

+ISNULL(LTRIM(RTRIM(CONVERT(CHAR(2),    


(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE

(REPLACE(REPLACE(SomeTable.DataColumn,''A'',''01''),''B'',''02''),
''C'',''03''),''D'',''03''),''E'',''03''))))),'''')

LEFT JOIN dbo.FOO_BAR_Mapping v ON v.Foo_promo_code=BarV.promocode 

    Where  Info.Startdate >= 
CONVERT(CHAR(20),DATEADD (WEEK , -1, GETDATE()),106)'  

  Execute (@SQLScript)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `case` statement instead of those many `replace` function. 
Try like below instead

```
select
case when DataColumn = 'A' then '01'
when DataColumn = 'B' then '02'
else '03' end as DataColumn_Formatted
from
(
select distinct
BarV.DataColumn
from SomeTable BarV
LEFT JOIN 
FOO_BAR_Mapping v 
ON v.Foo_promo_code=BarV.promocode 
Where  Info.Startdate >= 
CONVERT(CHAR(20),DATEADD (WEEK , -1, GETDATE()),106)
) tab
```

Comment: Thank you.  The syntax is different when added to a rather complicated INSERT INTO string, but using a CASE statement works.